# I want to filter the value in the Network tab using selenium-wire

Tags: python, selenium, seleniumwire

I use selenium-wire to capture the value when the download button is clicked.

main.py:

```
import os
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


def main():
    username = "adminbkh@gmail.com"
    password = "Adminbkh123@"
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option(
                "excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option(
                'useAutomationExtension', False)
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
                "download.prompt_for_download": False,
                "safebrowsing.enabled": True
            })
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
                ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)

    driver.maximize_window()

    driver.get("https://lovepik.com/video-42018/ocean-waves-roll-and-hit-the-scene.html")
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="user"]//*[@onclick="env.login();"]').click()
    driver.find_element(
                By.XPATH, '//form[@id="form-login-v4"]//*[@name="email"]').send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element(
                By.XPATH, '//form[@id="form-login-v4"]//*[@name="password"]').send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Login "]').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
    try:
        video = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="limit_down"]//*[@class="down_t"]')
        if video.is_displayed():
            video.click()
            print("This is a file video")
            time.sleep(5)
            for request in driver.requests:
                if request.response:
                    if "proxy-vip" in request.url:
                        print("Found")
                    else:
                        print("Not found")
        driver.close()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Couldn't find any elements")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When running main.py, there are many results returned. But I just want to get only the line "https://proxy-vip.lovepik.com/..." as shown in the photo below.

[results returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLNYu.png)

I try to find the value "proxy-vip" as in the code above. But the result printed to the screen is "Not found".

Please help me. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

you should not show all password, username in your questions as above

I don't know exactly why it is,
this is results when I run in jupyter notebook

[image]

The result will be printed to the screen when for loop is put apart, into other cell